# Fastlane Match - Nuke effect parse.com push and other third party services

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, app-store-connect, fastlane

I want to migrate my push notifications to match using fastlane and start over by nuking profiles and certificates. But I am reluctant, my app is on the appstore and I know from stackoverflow that revoking certificates should not effect my apps push notifications, but what if I am using Parse push and other 3rd parties that take my p12 for production. Will migrating to match disrupt my push notifications on production? If so, will uploading the newly generated p12 work or does the app need to be resubmitted.

Comment: "Will migrating to match disrupt my push notifications on production?" As I found out, it did. But I did use the nuke command.